# reading/saving array of characters in python

Tags: python, arrays

I am new in python and I would like to know if is it possible to read and store in an array a list/vector of characters:

```
1080
10-point
2,4,5-t
2,4-d
2D
2nd
3-D
3-d
3M
-a
A.
a'
a-
a.
```

This is a heterogeneous list of words/numbers/symbols that I would like to save and use, such as `if array(4) == 'c3M':` where array(4) means the 4-th element of the array.

Is there any fast way to define a function which read and store that file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will read in a file containing your example and store it in a Python list:

```
def file_lines_to_list(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return f.read().splitlines()

print(file_lines_to_list('example.txt'))
```

Output:

```
['1080', '10-point', '2,4,5-t', '2,4-d', '2D', '2nd', '3-D', '3-d', '3M', '-a', 'A.', "a'", 'a-', 'a.']
```

Python arrays are zero-based, so `array[0]` is the first element, `array[1]` is the second, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just save them in a list.

```
my_list = [item1,item2,item3]
```

and save it to a file say, 'file1.txt'
You can make a function that returns each of the items and also ADDS to the list.
**Note**: Python indexes start from 0 so item2 would be `my_list[1]`

```
from file1 import my_list

def display_item(index):
    return my_list[index]

def add_item(item):
    my_list.append(item)
    return my_list
```

And if that file ONLY contains the list you can then update it with the added items by changing the `add_item` function.

```
def add_item(item):
    my_list.append(item)
    f = open('file1.txt')
    f.write('my_list = %s'%(str(my_list)))
    f.close()
```